# Add tax label in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce and have taxes enabled, tax display for cart and checkout are set to be inclusive tax. So by default, Woocommerce adds a tax label after the subtotals and totals "(incl. VAT)". For customers who coe from a country with a 0 tax rate however, it does not show a tax label, it shows nothing. I need it to display "(excl. VAT)" though. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a filter

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_hide_zero_taxes', '__return_false' );`

Add this to your functions.php file.

Comment: this unfortunately does not add the "excl. tax" to subtotal. It only adds the tax amount(0%) to the total.

Comment: Do you enter prices including or excluding VAT?

Comment: Excluding, but everywhere in the frontend they need to be displayed as incl. VAT.

Comment: Could be that in the list of tax rates, you don't have anything set next to country code? Every country with 0%, needs to have it set there.

Comment: @Unnce No, I do have set up all the rates correctly. There is a dfference however if you set your 0% rates in the 0% rates tab or if you set it in the standard tabs and aplly 0%. But ths only has an effect on the "incl. ...$ VAT" that is displayed in the order-total cell, it has no effect on the "excl. VAT" or "incl. VAT" in the subtotal cell.